# lamplighter group - presentation and relations

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Regarding the lampligther group $\mathbb{Z}_2\wr\mathbb{Z}$, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group) (and other) gives the following presentation : 
$$\langle a, t \mid a^2, (a t^n a t^{-n})^2, n \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle$$
With the generating set:

- $a$ reflects the act of switching the lamp at the current position
- $t$ moves the position by $+1$

I'm looking at the following word : $w = atatat^{-2}at^2at^{-1}at^{-1}$ (which is basically saying I light on in order $0,1,2$ and then light off in order $0,2,1$). We can follow the state of the lamps as (starting with the initial state $e$)
$$\small\begin{array}{l|ccccccccccccc}
w&e&a&t&a&t&a&t^{-2}&a&t^2&a&t^{-1}&a&t^{-1}\\
\hline
\text{position}&0&0&1&1&2&2&0&0&2&2&1&1&0\\
\text{lights on}&\emptyset&\{0\}&\{0\}&\{0,1\}&\{0,1\}&\{0,1,2\}&\{0,1,2\}&\{1,2\}&\{1,2\}&\{1\}&\{1\}&\emptyset&\emptyset\\
\end{array}$$

It follows that $w=e$ and it should be part of the relations. However I don't see how to build it from $(a t^n a t^{-n})^2, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. For me these relations work for "pairs of lights", but they fail to capture other null actions when working on three lights if the light-on and light-off actions are not done in the same order...

However, the lamplighter group is well studied, and I doubt that there would be such a mistake in its presentation. Can anyone explain where I fail?

Comment: What you have is a *presentation*, not a representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relations say that $a$ commutes with $t^nat^{-n}$ for all $n \in {\mathbb Z}$. So, in the group we have
$$\begin{align}
w&=atatat^{-2}at^2at^{-1}at^{-1}\\
& = atata^2t^{-2}at^2t^{-1}at^{-1} \\
& =atatt^{-2}at^2t^{-1}at^{-1} \\
& =atat^{-1}atat^{-1} \\
& = ata^2t^{-1}att^{-1} \\
&=att^{-1}att^{-1} \\
& =a^2 \\
&=1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks I had missed that indeed. $(a t^n a t^{-n})^2 = e \Rightarrow a t^n a t^{-n} = (a t^n a t^{-n})^{-1}$, hence $a (t^n a t^{-n}) = (t^n a t^{-n}) a$ (with $a^2=e$).